# An instant messaging system by socket

Tags: sockets, multiprocessing

I want to implement an simple instant messaging system by socket.
 I should have a transit system (or a forwarding system), client A wants to send message to client B .

my server:

```
 sock_server = socket();
// I have shared memory to maintain a friendlist, shared by all child process
shared_friendlist[100];
...
while(1)
{
    sock_client = accept();
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid==0)  // one child process for one connection req
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }

}
```

firstly I thought each connection will keep a unique sock_client(accept() return value), I found I am totally wrong. the sock is unique for a (child process) not the total system.
So I think I can not send message like that;

one child process(sock_client_a):

```
read(sock_client_a,buffer_message,sizeof(buffer_message));
write(sock_client_n,buffer_message,sizeof(buffer_message));
```

because the child process did not know the sock_client_b.
how can I solve this problem? 
thanks very much.

Comment: If you want clients to communicate fork is not the right model. In fact I'd question whether there is any time fork is there right model today.

Comment: thanks for your help.But you mean the fork() is not the right model.how can I find a right model ,Please give me some advice,thank you.

Comment: Try to use threads. Look in internet for Unix's threads o similar. There are a lot of documents. A thread is a separate execution code inside your application, they can run simultaneously. You may have 1, 2 or many threads executing concurrently along with your app thread (main thread). You can start [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

Comment: thank you! thank you very much.I will learn and try threads.